# Mysql add primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `myenv` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `envid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`envid``) REFERENCES `envtable` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`userid``) REFERENCES `usertable` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Above table already i have two column with two foreign key.

Now i am planing to add the primary key on both column like below without remove foreign key.

see below new code:

```
CREATE TABLE `myenv` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `envid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (userid`,envid`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`envid``) REFERENCES `envtable` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`userid``) REFERENCES `usertable` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

This is right code ? could please give me idea it should be work or not ?

Comment: "This is right code ?"...Why don't you simply try it?

Comment: Yo have two backticks in a row and the two foreign key references should not have the same name.

Comment: YOu can change it direct from the old Table: ALTER TABLE `myenv` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`userid`,`envid`);

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY (\`userid\`,\`envid\`),`was missing the back quotes at the beginning of the column names.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are several issues here:

First you need to have the two tables you are referencing: `envtable` and `usertable` each having ID as primary key.

Then in table definition:

- You have miss-placed some backqoutes
- You have named the constraints
  the same.

Working code:

```
 CREATE TABLE `myenv` (
   `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `envid` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`userid`,`envid`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_myenv_envid` FOREIGN KEY (`envid`) REFERENCES `envtable` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_myenv_userid` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `usertable` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

It is a good idea to name the constraints with the following formula:

```
 CONSTRAINT-NAME_TABLE-NAME_COLUMN-NAME
```

This ensures the constraint name is unique database wise (note that not only unique in the same table).